# jQuery on.('click') event listner not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a simple loading symbol apear, when a person clicks on a button.
This is done using a simple removeClass function within jQuery.

However, i just cannot seem to get it to work.

The JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/061ehvko/4/

I have tried and change `.on('click', function()` to `.on('submit', function()` and `.on('mouseenter', function()` but none of this seems to solve the problem.

Regards,
Patrick

Comment: You have not added jQuery files in this fiddle. Try this http://jsfiddle.net/AmanVirdi/061ehvko/6/

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/061ehvko/5/. Yes you have not included jquery file.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/061ehvko/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

console says "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined "

you need to add jquery lib to use $

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Your fiddle does not include `JQuery`.

See my [update](http://jsfiddle.net/061ehvko/7/).

Comment: This should be comment.

Comment: Please put comments in the comment section (under the question). Answers should answer the question.

Comment: It does answer the question though doesn't it?

Comment: This is no comment it is the answer. OP didnt add the library